# Precision error when using OPENQUERY and Global Shop Solutions/Actian backend

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, actian, global-shop-solutions

I am querying Global Shop Solutions (backend is Actian) and I'm using `OPENQUERY` to perform an aggregate operation and then pull those records into SQL Server 2019. When I run the code below, I get this error:

> Msg 7354, Level 16, State 1, Line 54
> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "GSS" supplied invalid metadata for column "GSS_Total". The precision exceeded the allowable maximum.

When I remove the `SUM()` line, the error goes away. Not sure what is going on.

**The code:**

```
    select 
    
        * 
        
    from 
    
        openquery(GSS, '
                        select 
                        
                            h.purchase_order
                            , l.part
                            , l.record_no
                            , sum(l.qty_received) GSS_Total
                            , max(l.date_last_received) date_last_received
                            
                        from 
                        
                            v_po_header h 
                            inner join v_po_lines l on h.purchase_order = l.purchase_order

                        where

                            l.part like ''??-*''
                            and l.flag_recv_close <> ''Y''
                            and h.flag_recv_closed <> ''Y''
                            and h.type = 0
                            and substring(l.part, 17, 1) = ''''

                        group by

                            h.purchase_order
                            , l.part
                            , l.record_no
                            
                        ') t
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in their driver. Can you cast the SUM value to something "smaller"? I'm not sure what actian uses for actual dialect

Comment: What driver is in use for the "GSS" linked server?

Comment: @siggemannen casting to int works, but casting to decimal(5,0) does not

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers

Comment: do you know the actual database provider you're executing against? is it oracle or something else?

Comment: @siggemannen no clue. I know the end user product is called Global Shop Solutions and their program to interface with the backend is called Actian Zen 14 (similar to SSMS). And apparently this backend name is new - before, it was called Pervasive.

Comment: Heh, Pervasive, that takes me back!

Comment: @siggemannen small world, eh?

Comment: Does the query inside the OPENQUERY run correctly in the Actian Control Center or another ODBC tool?  What is the data type of the l.qty_received field?